# Pass json data using Gson and display RecyclerView but still display only last record in android

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I have create simple json data pass user first name and last name but i have display only one record but i have put intent in for loop this time multiple activity create and above for loop put intent this time display only one create.
And List size is database table value size.
Like this

FirstName            LastName

Android              corejava

Android              corejava

Android              corejava

Android              corejava

**My Json Activity **

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fn);
    ln = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ln);
    insert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insert1);
    show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(
                            new BasicHttpParams());

                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                            "http://192.168.2.5/Demo/lgin.php");

                    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                    InputStream inputStream = null;
                    String result = null;
                    try {
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient
                                .execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        inputStream = entity.getContent();

                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"),
                                8);

                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                        result = sb.toString();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            if (inputStream != null)
                                inputStream.close();
                        } catch (Exception squish) {

                        }
                    }
                    return result;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) { 
                    JSONObject jsonObj = null;
                    JSONArray jArray = null;
                    ArrayList<Model> data = new ArrayList<>();
                    try {
                        jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);
                        jArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("userdetail");

                        Model model = new Model();

                        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jObject = null;
                            jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                            model.setName(jObject.getString("user"));
                            model.setLastname(jObject.getString("pass"));


                            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "User = " + model.getName() + "Pas = " + model.getLastname());

                            data.add(model);

                        }
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewData.class);
                        intent.putExtra("data",new Gson().toJson(data));
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
            GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
            g.execute();

        }
    });


    insert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertURl, new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams()
                        throws AuthFailureError {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    parameters.put("user", fn.getText().toString());
                    parameters.put("pass", ln.getText().toString());
                    Log.d(getClass().getName(), "View =" + fn.getText().toString() + "LastNAme = " + ln.getText().toString());
                    return parameters;

                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(request);
        }
    });

}
```

**My Recyclerview Class**

```
public class ViewData extends Activity {
private AdapterFish mAdapter;
private List<Model> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.container_fish);

    String dataString = getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
    ArrayList<Model> list = new Gson().fromJson(dataString, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Model>>() {
    }.getType());
    mAdapter = new AdapterFish(ViewData.this, (ArrayList<Model>) list);
    RecyclerView mRVFishPrice = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.fishPriceList);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    mRVFishPrice.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRVFishPrice.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class AdapterFish extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
ArrayList<Model> data;
Model current;
int currentPos = 0;

// create constructor to innitilize context and data sent from MainActivity
public AdapterFish(Context context, ArrayList<Model> data) {
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlayout, parent, false);
    MyHolder holder = new MyHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MyHolder myHolder = (MyHolder) holder;
    Model model = data.get(position);
    myHolder.tvFirstName.setText(model.getName());
    myHolder.tvLastName.setText(model.getLastname());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tvFirstName;
    TextView tvLastName;


    // create constructor to get widget reference
    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tvFirstName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFirstName);
        tvLastName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvLastName);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: post your Recycler View adapter class that holding your onBindViewHolder() method.

Comment: Add my Adapterclass@SaurabhBhandari

Comment: Do not use View as object of 'List<Model>' give another name or use view instead of View

Comment: You are using Volley and apache http? I'd recommend only one library to do network request. Volley doesn't need AsyncTask

Comment: I have use list either View but not solve @SaurabhBhandari

Comment: But I have insert data using volley and I am new in web services@cricket_007

Comment: you are doing nothing inside `onResponse` of `volley` or maybe you want to do something later?

Comment: @User6829548 Is your all data printing in log cat or you are getting only last record.

Comment: Log time printing all data.@SaurabhBhandari

Answer (score 0):

**Convert your Array List into String using Gson and then pass it into Intent.**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewData.class);
    intent.putExtra("data",new Gson().toJson(data));
    startActivity(intent)
```

**Convert string back to list**

```
    String dataString = getIntent().getStringExtra("data") ;
    ArrayList<Model> list = new Gson().fromJson(dataString ,new TypeToken<ArrayList<Model>>(){}.getType());
```

**In Gradle**

```
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

Comment: I have put this code but java.lang.NullPointerException at com.example.post.AdapterFish.getItemCount how to solve it @Saurabh Padwekar

Comment: This method data is display but display only last data in database this error how to solve?@Saurabh Padwekar

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException error is solve but  
This method data is display but display only last data in database this error how to solve?

Comment: check the list size if it has all the data.

Comment: check in your adapter the getItemCount should be list.size()

Comment: list size is 5 but all value is same how could possible my database value is different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130896/discussion-between-user6829548-and-saurabh-padwekar).

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting your data in Your Log Cat then pass your ArrayList using following approach.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, ViewData.class);
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("data", data);
        startActivity(intent);
```

In your ViewData Activity you need to do

```
ArrayList<Model> list = new ArrayList<>();
 list = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("data");
```

Pass list ti the your RecyclerView Adapter Class

```
mAdapter = new AdapterFish(ViewData.this, (ArrayList<Model>) list);
```

Comment: Not Possible are you try this In my case i have send data using model class so i have no used putStringArrayListExtra

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Model model ;

                        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                            model = new Model();
                            JSONObject jObject = null;
                            jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                            model.setName(jObject.getString("user"));
                            model.setLastname(jObject.getString("pass"));


                            Log.d(getClass().getName(), "User = " + model.getName() + "Pas = " + model.getLastname());

                            data.add(model);

                        }
```

or

```
 Gson gson = new Gson();
                data = gson.fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<ArrayList<Model>>() {
                }.getType());
```

Comment: I have Already add this in my code plz check my qu?@Avinash kumawat

Comment: nothing is wrong with your code but a small fix in your Json activity, initialise your model class in your for loop not outside the loop. and Can you plz share the custom_layout.xml?